# How to get location continously?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have an app that tracks user location continously. Now, this works as follows:
I have foreground service that schedules repeating alarm via *AlarmManager*. *Alarm Receiver* in *onReceive* method starts service again. Inside service Im receiving current location from Locator (singleton class that gets location form GP Services). Alarm manager fires alarm once in a 12 minutes, and I want to set repeating time to 1 minute or less. But i`m aware of too frequenlty waking up device - I think it will consump battery very fast.
This foreground service works always. 
Are there any other, better way to track location continously?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478179/background-service-with-location-listener-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You can use LocationListener.
[google location listner](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout answer on this thread: [Getting location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987099/cant-get-gps-coordinates-in-android-application/44987300#44987300)

In above answer, while creating object for LocationRequest call these two methods, `setFastestInterval(long interval)` and `setInterval(long interval)` which will fetch location after some interval.